# How to convert RGB Pixel Buffer to IRandomAccessStream^

Tags: c++, stream, uwp, type-conversion, c++-cx

I have structure like this:

```
struct PixelBuffer
{
    unsigned int width,height,stride;
    PixelFormat format;
    unsigned char * buffer;
}
```

I want to convert it to **IRandomAccessStream^** how do I do that? (bytes that buffer is pointing to)

I am not sure if PixelFormat makes difference and if there is favourable one, but let's say it is **RGB** format.

Thanks!

**Note**

I need **SoftwareBitmap^** So my idea is to get IRandomAccessStream^ and then get BitmapDecoder^ from which I would get SoftwareBitmap^ if there is some shortcut that I am not aware of that would be great!

Comment: You need write a class deriving from `IRandomAccessStream` and implementing all the required methods.

Comment: Is this the only way? Will it work same as IRandomAccessStream? And how do I implement it in a way to work with this PixelBuffer, do I send it through constructor ? I am sorry if these questions are stupid I just never implemented custom IRandomAccessStream, and I am not sure how hard it is

Comment: I have found this article https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/06/06/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-irandomaccessstream/ is it similar for C++ ?

Comment: Yes, `IRandomAccessStream` is just a COM interface. You derive your class from it and then implement all the pure virtual methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go through Stream if SoftwareBitmap^ is what you need, you can get it directly from buffer like this

```
vector<unsigned char> bufferBGRA; // Convert your bytes to BGRA
DataWriter ^writer = ref new DataWriter();
writer->WriteBytes(Platform::ArrayReference<BYTE>(
            bufferBGRA.data(), 
            width * height * 4)); // 4 channels (BGRA)
IBuffer ^buff= writer->DetachBuffer();

// Create SoftwareBitmap from buff
SoftwareBitmap^ softwareBitmap = ref new SoftwareBitmap(BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, width, height);
softwareBitmap->CopyFromBuffer(buff);
```

And yeah in this case **BGRA is the favorable format**, since you will need to convert your buffer to the format that **BitmapPixelFormat** supports like BGRA